# How can i guarantee that if a is a type of A, then b is a type of B in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

Let's assume that we have several types:

```
interface ModalType {
   preview: ReactElement;
   edit: ReactElement;
}


interface PreviewModalProps {
   username: string;
}

interface EditModalProps {
   title: string;
   description: string;
}


type ModalPropsType = PreviewModalProps | EditModalProps;

const modals: ModalType = {
   preview: <PreviewModalComponent />
   edit: <EditModalComponent />
}

type ModalName = keyof ModalType;

const modalName: ModalName = 'preview'

// pass it somewhere else
```

In this example I want to be sure, that if our `modalName` has the `preview` value,then our props should correspond to a `PreviewModalProps`, not the `EditModalProps`.

How can I connect it everything toghether?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine ModalProps,

Combining with "&" operator, you can achieve it.

```js
type ModalPropsType = {
  name: "preview"
} & PreviewModalProps | {
  name: "edit"
} & EditModalProps;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that at the *top* level, but you can easily do that by creating a couple of wrappers to form a *discriminated union*:

```
interface Preview {
  name: 'preview' // NOTE: this is a string literal *type*
  props: PreviewModalProps
}

interface Edit {
  name: 'edit' // ditto
  props: EditModalProps
}
```

If you use those interfaces the compiler won't let you assign the wrong ones, and if you check the discriminant (name in this case) in a conditional the compiler will narrow the type:

```
function doesTheThing(x: Preview | Edit) {
  if (x.name === 'preview') {
    // here compiler knows we have PreviewModalProps for x.props
  } else {
    // here compiler knows x.props must be EditModalProps
  }
```